# Turkey brining efficiently and safely

Tags: turkey, brining, safety, thanksgiving

Trying to menu plan for Thanksgiving in between a busy work schedule. Here is my current plan:

Monday - Cook neck and giblets (thus removing turkey from packaging) to create stock for gravy and stuffing. Also cook my turkey brine and cool it.

Tuesday - Put turkey in brine.

Wednesday - Remove turkey from brine, rinse, dry and leave in fridge.

Thursday - Cook the bird.

Between sitting raw on Monday, brining on Tuesday and sitting in the fridge on Wednesday, is this too many days to hold a raw turkey before cooking it? Or will the brine help preserve it for the extra day beyond the USDA recommended 1-2 days?